# Java 1.4 : RandomAccesFile returning null value when array byte is over

Tags: java

This class is part of the multi user application and it's used to view documents, however this does not work when the file size is over 20 MB.

The issue is here:

```
raf = new RandomAccessFile(this._file, "rw");
byte[] b = new byte[128000];
```

I have also tried to change it to `byte[] b = new byte[(int)raf];` but it did not work.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

class PersistentByteServerV2$Runner extends Thread {
 private ReaderWriterLock _rwl;
 private File _file;
 private InputStream _is;
 private long _bytesRead;
 private boolean _locksAcquired = true;

 public PersistentByteServerV2$Runner(ReaderWriterLock rwl, File file,
  InputStream is) {
  this._rwl = rwl;

  try {
   this._rwl.startWrite();
   this._rwl.startRead();
  } catch (InterruptedException var5) {
   this._locksAcquired = false;
  }

  this._file = file;
  this._is = is;
  this._bytesRead = 0 L;
 }

 public void run() {
  RandomAccessFile raf = null;
  if (this._locksAcquired) {
   try {
    raf = new RandomAccessFile(this._file, "rw");
    byte[] b = new byte[128000]; // the value is set to this, as changing it to raf length does not work.
    long len = 0 L;

    do {
     len = (long) this._is.read(b); //InputStream
     if (len <= 0 L) {
      break;
     }

     raf.write(b, 0, (int) len); //write to the random access file
     if (this._bytesRead == 0 L) {
      this._rwl.endRead();
     }

     this._bytesRead += len;
    } while (len > -1 L);
   } catch (Throwable var18) {;
   } finally {
    try {
     raf.close();
    } catch (Throwable var17) {;
    }

    try {
     this._is.close();
    } catch (Throwable var16) {;
    }

    if (this._rwl.isWriterDown()) {
     this._rwl.endWrite();
    }

    if (this._rwl.isReaderDown()) {
     this._rwl.endRead();
    }

   }

  }
 }

 public long getBytesRead() {
  try {
   this._rwl.startRead();
   this._rwl.endRead();
  } catch (InterruptedException var2) {
   return -1 L;
  }

  return this._bytesRead;
 }
}
```

Comment: what is returning `null`?  Is there any stacktrace?

Comment: `catch (Throwable var18) {;
   }` - should not silently swallow exceptions.

Comment: Hi Scary ... raf = new RandomAccessFile(this._file, "rw");
    byte[] b = new byte[128000];  When the number of array byte is set to anything above 128000 the below code does not execute.

Comment: what do you mean *does not execute* ?

Comment: I meant to say  if I change this  byte[] b = new byte[128000]; to byte[] b = new byte[30305532]  so bigger files can be read. The value for this._bytesRead  is 0;

Comment: well in reality you are better off reading smaller blocks, and looping.  e.g. 8K block seems to work well.

Comment: thanks Scary.. The code is already doing that :

Comment: thanks Scary.. The code is already doing that :  byte[] b = new byte[128000]; // the value is set to this, as changing it to raf length does not work.
    long len = 0 L;

    do {
     len = (long) this._is.read(b); //InputStream
     if (len <= 0 L) {
      break;
     }